# Proving the transition map of a smooth surface is smooth

Tags: differential-geometry

First of all, this is not a homework problem, so please do give whatever advice/criticism you can give.

I'm reading Pressley's Elementary Differential Geometry and he gives the theorem that transition maps of a smooth surface are smooth.  I'm confused why we can't use the following proof (he waits to talk about the inverse function theorem to write the proof):

Let $U,\tilde{U}\subset \Bbb{R}^2$ and $W,\tilde{W}\subset\Bbb{R}^3$

Suppose $S$ is a smooth surface, thus $\exists \sigma: U \rightarrow S \cap W$ such that $\sigma$ is smooth.  Similarly $\exists \tilde{\sigma}: \tilde{U} \rightarrow S \cap \tilde{W}$ such that $\tilde{\sigma}$ is smooth.  Trivially $\sigma:U\rightarrow S\cap W\cap \tilde{W}$ and $\tilde{\sigma}:\tilde{U}\rightarrow S\cap W \cap \tilde{W}$.

If we define $\Phi:U\rightarrow\tilde{U}$ st $\Phi=\tilde{\sigma}^{-1}\circ\sigma$, then $\Phi$ is the composition of smooth functions, thus $\Phi$ is smooth.

$\square$

Comment: How do you know that $\tilde{\sigma}^{-1}$ is smooth? Usually, one gets that from the inverse function theorem.

Comment: @DanielFischer I see, thanks!